# Does the holographic principle in physics, if true, rule out the existence of infinite sets in mathematics?

Tags: set-theory, physics

The holographic principle sets an upper bound on the number of bits of information in the universe.  See for example https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/information-in-the-holographic-univ/

One of the fundamental statements in set theory is that the elements of a set can be assigned distinct symbols.  An assignment assumes that the elements' identities can be recorded somewhere, at least in principle.  If there is an upper limit on information in the universe, then only sets below a certain finite size can have all of their elements assigned a symbol.  This is not an engineering constraint, but a deep fundamental physics constraint on the nature of reality. This would seem to rule out the possible existence of infinite sets.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think the downvotes here are excessive. And to the OP, I suspect that they may be due to the fact that a very similar question was recently asked by a well-known spammer, who then proceeded to insult the people who responded; since this spammer has a habit of using many different usernames and re-asking their closed questions, there might be some suspicion with regards to this question. To the downvoters, note that the OP has an account at the physics stackexchange where they have given multiple upvoted answers, so I don't believe they are the spammer in question.

Comment: That said, I think your question might be better received if you would try to justify the first sentence of your second paragraph . . .

Comment: It's a bit philosophical for Math.SE, but I think it a reasonable Question (and might be justified without an appeal to "the holographic principle").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The emphasis below is mine.*

> One of the fundamental statements in set theory is that the elements of a set can be assigned distinct symbols. An assignment assumes that the elements' identities can be recorded **somewhere**, at least in principle.

No. That's just not a thing set theory assumes. Or rather, it could be if you interpret your statement sufficiently broadly, but this broad interpretation removes all connection with the physical universe (and is so broad as to be tautological in my opinion).

This issue is seen more clearly in your statement

> This would seem to rule out the possible **existence** of infinite sets.

This relies on a very specific notion of "existence," which in general is not how mathematicians use the word.

The question of what mathematics can be "represented" in the physical universe is a very interesting one, and one might reasonably argue that infinite sets do not have "physical meaning", but since set theory and mathematics in general make no ontological commitment relating mathematical existence to the physical universe this is of limited relevance in general.

Comment: By the way, the question of what mathematicians *do* mean by "existence" is a really interesting one, about which much is written - but that's a question for another time.

Comment: In the last sentence, "limited relevance" is an understatement.